# Python and Requests on Mac OS, reporting deployment events to Stackdriver

Tags: python, macos, import

I am trying to run this example from http://support.stackdriver.com/customer/portal/articles/1491725-sending-code-deploy-events-to-stackdriver

```
import requests
import json

def submit_code_deploy_event():
    """ Submit a code deploy event to Stackdriver """

    headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json',
                'x-stackdriver-apikey': '<YOURAPIKEY>' }

    deploy_event = { 'revision_id': '87230611cdc7e5ff7723a91e715367c553ad1115',
                     'deployed_by': 'JoeyI',
                     'deployed_to': 'production',
                     'repository':  'prototype_dashboard' }

    resp = requests.post( 'https://event-gateway.stackdriver.com/v1/deployevent',
                          data=json.dumps(deploy_event),
                          headers=headers)

    assert resp.ok, 'Failed to submit code deploy event.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    submit_code_deploy_event()
```

but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

So I ran:

```
➜  pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (452kB): 452kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

but the error persists:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Running on Mac OS, python 2.75
Ideas?
(feel like a noob)

Answer (score 0):

had you installed a python interpreter different from the system? there is a common problem when you are developing using OSX, I recommend to install `virtualenv` and treat all the dependencies in virtual environments.

These other things can help you:

- Locate pip with `which pip` and see this content to see which python version is using
- Locate you version of python (`which python`) and see if it's similar to the pip enviroment
- if you are using macports o homebrew be sure to replace the default Python interpreter with these versions (it does not automatically).

Comment: ➜  ~  which pip

/usr/local/bin/pip

➜  ~  which python

/usr/bin/python

Comment: open the pip script with a text editor and see which python version is using, in my case is: `#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`